# How to limit the number of data to be displayed in an array vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have a list of values inside data array. I wanted to display the first two values (0 and 1), and display the button show_more. If the button is clicked, another set of values (2, 3) are displayed and then the button must be clicked to show more data.

Please see the code below:

```
<div id="app">
 <h2>List:</h2>
 <div v-for="(d, index) in data">
  <!-- display 0 and 1, then after a button is clicked, display 2 & 3, 
       and then a button is clicked, display 4 & 5, and so on..  -->
    {{ d }}
  </div>
</div>
<script>
new Vue({
 el: "#app",
 data() {
   return{
     data:[0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
   }
 }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a computed method that takes care of filtering the array depending on whatever conditions you have.

Add a limit on your data:

```
data() {
  return {
    data: [...],
    limit: 2
  }
}
```

Update `limit` from button click:

```
<button @click="limit += 2"> More </button>
```

Return filtered data:

```
computed: {
 filteredData() {
   return this.data.filter( (el, index) => index < limit) )
 }
}
```

Now use `filteredData` instead of `data`

```
<div v-for="(d, index) in filteredData">
```

Having the filtering logic in a computed property makes it easier to add more conditions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Use `v-for` on just a [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) of `data`:

```
<div v-for="(d, index) in data.slice(listStart, listEnd)">
```

Then adjust `listStart` and `listEnd` as necessary.

Comment: how could get the listStart and listEnd since this is a dynamic data?

Comment: @smzapp store them in your component's `data()`